# GWT ListBox with HasValue and @UiTemplate

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I am trying to use `ListBox` with `HasValue` interface implemented, I got code / idea from the following link and I made the my own list box class

http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/selectonelistbox-for-use-with-gwtmvp/

Now the problem is I am using `@UiTemplate` in my Views and I am finding it difficult to cast `ListBox` to this new `ListBox`.

My View class code:

```
// defines List Box , so it get attached with UiTemplate
 @UiField ListBox countryListBox ;

//-- this function should get the list box, i call this in presenter...
//-- now the problem is i do not know how i take this listbox back as selectOneListBox
 public HasSelectedValue <T> getCountry() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return desTextBox;
        SelectOneListBox<T> sel = new SelectOneListBox<T>(null);
        sel =(SelectOneListBox<T>) countryListBox;
        //return  (SelectOneListBox<T>) countryListBox;
        return sel;
        //return countryListBox ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `ListBox` to `SelectOneListBox` ("this new `ListBox`"), because `ListBox` is not an implementation of `SelectOneListBox`. Unlsee you have reference to `ListBox`, but in fact you keep `SelectOneListBox` in it. However I doubt it, because then your code should work.

Show us some code if you want to help us help you.

Comment: I am using the SelectOneListBox as given in blog, The ListBox i want to show will have country list in it , i tried to cast it like below but it gives me exception 

public HasSelectedValue <T> getCountry() {
 SelectOneListBox<T> sel = new SelectOneListBox<T>(null);
 sel =(SelectOneListBox<T>) countryListBox;
 //return  (SelectOneListBox<T>) countryListBox;
 return sel;
 //return countryListBox ;
}

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put your code there? It is not readable in comment.